# Define var outside the if-else statement scope for later use

Tags: c#, linq

I have an if-else statement which gets search results from database using Linq, each one is different than the other, but the returned type if the same.

My problem is that I can't initialize the `var` variable outside the if-else statement. I need it because after the statement I continue to query the results.

The result is of type `iQueryable<mission>`;

How can I make the var in the function scope be able to accept the results?

I tried initializing it with `Enumerable.Empty<mission>().AsQueryable()` and it didn't work, tried using `dynamic` variable and set also set the `var missions = null`, and it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you show the code in question and the errors that you are receiving?

Comment: What's wrong with `IQueryable<Mission> = null;`?

Comment: Then change the var into the correct type and assign it wil null or a default value

Comment: Can you not just create an IQueryable<mission> instead of a var?

Comment: It's not mandatory to define variables as `var`, you can define it as `IQueryable<mission>` outside `if`

Comment: @ClaudioRedi didn't know that. Using iQueryable<mission> works. thanks for enlightening me. The solution was right there, but I didn't know how to approach it.

Comment: The only time you actually **need** `var` is if you're using an anonymous type, in which case dealing with your sort of situation can be tricky and often impossible, forcing one to create a new type for the code to work. In other cases `var` is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @JonHanna Thanks, I understand it completely now.

Comment: @JonHanna Interestingly, it's possible to fake the compiler into allowing even the anonymous type - all the anonymous types with the same definition can resolve to the same type under certain conditions. So you can do something like `var p = new { SomeField = default(string) };` and then use the same local for any other anonymous type that has a single `SomeField` field of type `string`. Generic methods can also help exploit this behaviour.

Comment: @Luaan right you are, and I've even done that myself, but had forgotten. It *feels* like waste, but it isn't really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So... don't use `var`?

```
IQueryable<Mission> variable;

if (...)
{
  ...
```

Also, as an alternative to `var variable = null` (which doesn't compile), you can use `default`:

```
var variable = default(IQueryable<Mission>);
```

Unlike the code above, though, this will hide errors stemming from "forgetting" to assign to the variable - you're assigning a "typed" `null`, so the variable has a value assigned. In the first example, `variable` isn't *assigned*, so if there's any branch of your code that tries to read the value of `variable` *without* writing to it first, the compiler will report an error. Also note that `default` only returns `null` for reference types. Value types will basically return whatever zero means for that particular type - for example, `default(int)` is simply zero, and `default(DateTime)` is `01/01/0001 00:00:00` (`DateTime.MinValue`).

Comment: Simple solution, just haven't thought about doing it this way. Noob me, but thanks for enlighten me. I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler has to be able to determine the *actual* type of a `var` variable *at compile time*. If you do this:

```
var foo = null;
```

Or this:

```
var foo;
```

What's the type of `foo`? You can't tell, and neither can the compiler.

So if you need to have a variable set to `null`, you have to *tell the compiler what type it is*:

```
IQueryable<Mission> foo = null;
```

Or, if you don't want to initialize it yet:

```
IQueryable<Mission> foo;
```

Look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) reference on implicitly typed local variables. In particular:

> The var keyword instructs the compiler to infer the type of the variable from the expression on the right side of the initialization statement.

You can't infer a type from `null` and you certainly can't do it if there is no expression on the right-hand side.

Also:

> var can only be used when a local variable is declared and initialized in the same statement; the variable cannot be initialized to null, or to a method group or an anonymous function.